# How can I run apt update over a VPN connection?

Tags: debian, apt, vpn

Using the default sources.list

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
```

`apt update` works fine when not connected to a VPN, but after connecting to a VPN, `apt update` times out for the `bullseye` and `bullseye-security` components:

```
$ apt update
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [113 kB]
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  Connection timed out [IP: 151.101.54.132 80]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [44.1 kB]
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
  Connection timed out [IP: 151.101.54.132 80]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [36.8 kB]
Fetched 36.8 kB in 1min 1s (601 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Connection timed out [IP: 151.101.54.132 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Connection timed out [IP: 151.101.54.132 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I run `apt update` over a VPN connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `deb.debian.org` does stricter VPN blocking than some of the mirrors. Updating your sources.list to use a [local mirror](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list) for the `bullseye` component, and the `security` subdomain for the `security` component, may allow `apt update` to proceed. For example, the following sources.list works for me in the US when connected to a VPN:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main
```